# How to find an element in an <iframe> (none: id; none: classname) to action?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, iframe, captcha

I'm looking for element xpath <'/html/body/div/div[2]'> to be able to do automatic button hold down using selenium python, however I'm having difficulty since they are inside iframe.
I tried "Expected_conditions as EC" but I'm not knowledgeable enough to make them work. Tell me what to change, or a more sensible approach.

HTML:

```html
<div id="px-captcha" role="main">
  <iframe style="display: none; width: 310px; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="951d7e81fd6fb5e2af2cb2c701dbb6c391ab81d4b983da5f2f2de85667241a43a3a814a87cae2e98c70b730f7eaaac0a04bbf77bbfc63735e436d1d07675cb68"></iframe>
  <iframe style="display: block; width: 310px; height: 100px; border: 0; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;" token="951d7e81fd6fb5e2af2cb2c701dbb6c391ab81d4b983da5f2f2de85667241a43a3a814a87cae2e98c70b730f7eaaac0a04bbf77bbfc63735e436d1d07675cb68">
    #document
    <html lang="en-US"
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
      <div id="kkBSsePnKDMVkwa" class="eIlUWbNLSMdFkEz">
        <div id="#LrJbZYBfdAzlAkl"></div>
        <div id="BlXIkuwFPcwvDCY" role="main" aria-label="Please press and hold the button until verified">...</div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
  </iframe>
  <iframe style="display: none; width: 310px; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="951d7e81fd6fb5e2af2cb2c701dbb6c391ab81d4b983da5f2f2de85667241a43a3a814a87cae2e98c70b730f7eaaac0a04bbf77bbfc63735e436d1d07675cb68"></iframe>
  <p style="color: red; margin-top: 4;">Please try again</p>
</div>
```

Code (Updated)#Error:

```js
def captcha(url):
    driver.get(str(url))
    time.sleep(10)
    try:
        captcha_element = driver.find_element_by_id('px-captcha')
        print(len(captcha_element.text), 'Captcha verification request page')
        print('Run pass captcha programing')
        # 2.1: Verify captcha
        # Research iframe containing captcha
        
        # # Example 2: Use pyautogui library
        # driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        # driver.set_window_size(1024, 640)
        # sleep(randint(5,10))
        # pyautogui.moveTo(400, 438)
        # pyautogui.click()
        # pyautogui.dragTo(596, 438, 5, button='left')

        # Example 3:
        for i in range(10):
            try:
                wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe)[{i}]"))) #ERROR HERE. TO TRY REPLACEMENT <wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe)[2]")))>
                print ("- Found iframe")
                element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Please press and hold the button until verified')]")
                print ("- Found element")
                # click and hold 5 seconds to pass the captcha
                print("Button verify: ", len(element.text))
                action = ActionChains(driver)
                click = ActionChains(driver)
                frame_x = element.location['x']
                frame_y = element.location['y']
                print("x: ", frame_x)
                print("y: ", frame_y)
                print("size box: ", element.size)
                print("x max click: ", frame_x + element.size['width'])
                print("y max click: ", frame_y + element.size['height'])
                x_move = frame_x + element.size['width']/2
                y_move = frame_y + element.size['height']/2
                print("Click (x,y) = ", x_move, y_move)
                action.move_to_element_with_offset(element, x_move, y_move).click_and_hold().perform()
                time.sleep(10)
                action.release(element)
                action.perform()
                time.sleep(0.2)
                action.release(element)
                print('Verify successful')
                break
            except:
                print(f'- NOT Found xpath Num.: {i}')  
        sleep(randint(5,10))

    except:
        # 2.2: Skip captcha
        print('Website does NOT require captcha verification')
        sleep(randint(2,3))
```

I wanted  find element:

```html
<div id="BlXIkuwFPcwvDCY" role="main" aria-label="Please press and hold the button until verified">...</div>
```

Comment: get list of number of `iframes` by tag name. Like `driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));` and use the specific `iframe` to switch. Please let me know the outcome.

Comment: <iframe_ele = captcha_element.find_elements_by_xpath('/iframe['+str(i)+']')> to <iframe_ele = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(By.TAG_NAME('iframe['+str(i)+']'))> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with this web element :

```
<div id="BlXIkuwFPcwvDCY" role="main" aria-label="Please press and hold the button until verified">...</div>
```

you need to switch to this iframe first :

```
<iframe style="display: block; width: 310px; height: 100px; border: 0; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;" token="951d7e81fd6fb5e2af2cb2c701dbb6c391ab81d4b983da5f2f2de85667241a43a3a814a87cae2e98c70b730f7eaaac0a04bbf77bbfc63735e436d1d07675cb68">
```

Now since you have mentioned that we are not able to find any any unique identifier for this, I would probably use it's parent div `<div id="px-captcha" role="main">`

Something like this :-

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe)[2]")))
```

and then can interact with the desired web element.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@aria-label, 'Please press and hold the button until verified')]").click()
```

You are gonna need the below imports as well :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):  line 185 <module> wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe[2]")))
Error: "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: My command line is stopped with the command as above. Also, my html has 10 similar iframes and the element is randomly in those 10 iframes after each page load

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe[2]` if your desired element is getting highlighted

Comment: and see if there is 1/1 matching, or 1/2 or anything else. It has be 1/1 and the iframe we want it should highlight that as well. also try to adjust [2] to [3] or [4] to see if we have 1/1 matching element in the DOM

Comment: element is getting highlighted (yellow) with Crl+F <//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe[2]>, and "1 of 1". Same for the remaining 9 iframes, they are unique.

Comment: Try this `(//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe)[2]`

Comment: @NandanA : I think that should do, thanks, I should have applied xpath indexing at first place. I have updated above, OP can try that out and let us know if that worked or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing @cruisepandey. I used the indexes xpath and libraries to run as you mentioned, but the program always crashes at the line <wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='px)" -captcha']/iframe)[2]")))>

Comment: @NandanA I've tried running this do-by-line program, but it always stops here:
> wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "(//div[@id='px-captcha']/iframe)[2]"))) <
Right now I'm using pyautogui as a temporary solution, but you know pyautogui hijacks the user's mouse